# How to deploy Clojure/Luminus uberwar in Weblogic 12.c

Tags: clojure, weblogic12c, luminus

I have created a microservice PoC using Clojure & Luminus web framework and packaged into a WAR via **lein uberwar**.

It has been tested and it is properly deployed and run in **Immutant** and **Tomcat** servers. Our production environment is an **Oracle Weblogic 12c**. In order to avoid some errors I've created a *weblogic.xml* file inside the war with the content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app
    xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<container-descriptor>
  <filter-dispatched-requests-enabled>false</filter-dispatched-requests-enabled>
  <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>      
</container-descriptor>
```

However I get this internal error as if the server would not detect the entry point of the application.

```
<Nov 10, 2016 9:25:57 AM UTC> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener mu_publisher.listener failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not start [#'mu-publisher.handler/init-app] due to.
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not start [#'mu-publisher.handler/init-app] due to
at mount.core$up$fn__4349.invoke(core.cljc:92)
at mount.core$up.invokeStatic(core.cljc:92)
at mount.core$up.invoke(core.cljc:90)
at mount.core$bring.invokeStatic(core.cljc:206)
at mount.core$bring.invoke(core.cljc:198)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :enabled? of protocol: #'clojure.tools.logging.impl/Logger found for class: org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter
at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invokeStatic(core_deftype.clj:568)
at clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn.invoke(core_deftype.clj:560)
at clojure.tools.logging.impl$fn__51$G__44__58.invoke(impl.clj:16)
at mu_publisher.env$fn__225.invokeStatic(env.clj:7)
at mu_publisher.env$fn__225.invoke(env.clj:6)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

As an update. I modified the **weblogic.xml** as:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app
    xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<container-descriptor>
  <filter-dispatched-requests-enabled>false</filter-dispatched-requests-enabled>
  <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>org.slf4j</package-name>
      <package-name>org.joda.*</package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>    </container-descriptor>
```

So I no longer get the error message. But when I try to access the webapp via **http://localhost:8001/mu-publisher**, I get an **ERROR 500: Something very bad happened**, and in the console log's no errors are reflected or printed.

Comment: If this is an update you should update your question instead.